# How to Read values from a properties file in thymleaf

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Is there a way to read values from properties file in thymleaf using spring boot?
eg:- validation messages, load labels from the properties file.

I'm using **spring boot 2.1.3 version & thymleaf 3.0.11 version** 
I need to dynamically set labels in my application using the properties file. I couldn't find a way to access properties file directly in thymleaf.

I tried creating **lables.properties** file in resources 
eg:-

```
field1 = "Name"
field2 = "Description"
```

I tried to access in thymleaf using like this,

```
<a href="./admin"><p class="text-uppercase" th:text="#{field1}"></p></a>
```

But it was not working like this.

It displays as **??label1_en_US??"** in my HTML view.
Can anyone help me for sort this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to rename your `lables.properties` to `messages.properties` to get it resolved by Spring Boot automatically.

If this still is not working, consider defining an explicit message source like:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:/messages");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageSource;
}
```

The basenames are basically the name of your properties files with out the `.properties` extension.

Comment: Thanks for the answer its really helpful. Both options u provided working fine. i need to clarify one thing when i write  explicit message source i wrote it in Spring boot main class is it correct or do i have to write it in a different way?

Comment: Thank you. Well regarding main class or not. If you have a rather small application and this would be your only manually defined bean, I would put it into the main class. If your app tends to be larger, a logical separation of config beans makes sense. At the end it's really up to you!

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out now I figured what I really want. Thanks again in advance.